# Get all but the last item in an R list

Tags: r, list

```
x <- list("item one", "item two", "item three")
```

If I wanted to select all but the last item in Python, I would use `x[:-1]`. How do I do this in R?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
x[-length(x)] # or 
head(x, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can tell R to take one less than the `length` of the entire vector: `x[1:length(x)-1]`